# python datetime.datetime return two different types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe returning two differents types:

```
>contrats[["DT_DEB_CTRT","DT_FIN_REELLE"]].ix[0]
DT_DEB_CTRT      2012-01-05:00:00:00
DT_FIN_REELLE    2013-01-31:00:00:00
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

When I want to convert the dates in datetime I got two different kind of returns :

```
>contrats.DT_DEB_CTRT = contrats.DT_DEB_CTRT.apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d%b%Y:00:00:00"))
>contrats.DT_FIN_REELLE = contrats.DT_FIN_REELLE.apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%d%b%Y:00:00:00"))
```

On one I get a datetime object :

```
>contrats.DT_FIN_REELLE[0]
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 31, 0, 0)
```

but In another, I get a timestamp :

```
>contrats.DT_DEB_CTRT[0]
Timestamp('2012-01-05 00:00:00')
```

Any idea why ??

EDIT

```
contrats.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4291241 entries, 0 to 4291240
Data columns (total 15 columns):
DT_DEB_CTRT               object
DT_FIN_REELLE             object
dtypes: float64(7), object(8)
memory usage: 491.1+ MB
```

Comment: Can you post the output from `contrats.info()` depending on how you constructed the df, one maybe `datetime64` while the other will show `object` when in fact it's `datetime` or `Timestamp`

Comment: seems both are recognised as objects :(

Comment: what version numpy and pandas are you using and can you post raw data and code to reproduce this

Comment: pd.__version__ = 0.18.0

Comment: I din't use numpy (but it is version 1.11.0)

Comment: difficult to reproduce :(

Answer (score 0):

It appeared that I had a date in "9999/12/31", which made a mess.